# Error with ImportXML for importing Data in Google-Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML() function in google sheets to grab a specific item of text on this website (https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/advice/XRP.CC?), however, I keep getting errors.

" "Error" Loading Data "

I want to scrape this block of HTML text

`<div class="adviseText" style="margin-top:-77px">Strong Sell</div>`

I've tried using the XPATH & Full XPATH which appear like this,

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/advice/XRP.CC?riskLevel=60&dayRange=6","//*[@id='container']/div[13]/div[3]")`

This did not work. I read that it may be as a result of the 'container', so I tried it using the class name of the text I needed, however this did not work either!

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/advice/XRP.CC?riskLevel=60&dayRange=6","//span[@class='adviseText']")`

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/advice/XRP.CC?riskLevel=60&dayRange=6",
 "//div[@class='adviseText']")
```

[image]